# R Pearson rank correlation between two tissues for numerous analytes aand timepoints

Tags: r, data-science, pearson-correlation

New to R and programming, but working on this skill to work through very large data sets.  For this exercise, I would like to perform rank correlations between two types of samples for multiple analytes (>50) at various timepoints (i.e. baseline, month 1).  I can work through it manually, each analyte and timepoint one by one, but it would awesome if I could get some support to automate to compare analytes in each tissues at the various timepoint.  Finally, I would like to generate a data table that lists all the correlations by rank.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I have included images of the data frame and some of my code below.

Here is an example of the table:

[image]

Here is some of my code to get correlation for one analyte (IL-8):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Maybe you want `pairwise_cor()` from package `widyr`?